# hiding app icon and start the Activity through dialerpad

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, logcat

In my application I want to open my application when pressing the code 5556 through dialerpad otherwise its icon remains hidden from menu of my mobile.

To open the application Activity page through dialerpad I used the code(Broadcast receiver):-

```
Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
            if (null == bundle)
                return;

            String phoneNubmer = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
                //here change the number to your desired number
                String compare_num="5556";
                if(phoneNubmer.equals(compare_num))
                {
                    setResultData(null);
                //  Guardian.changeStealthMode(context,PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED);
                    Intent myintent=new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
                    myintent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    context.startActivity(myintent);
```

and to hide the icon I used (In MainActivity):-

```
PackageManager p =context.getPackageManager();
        ComponentName componentName=new ComponentName(context,MainActivity.class);
        p.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName, 
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, 
                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

But while running on avd I get following errors:-

```
[2013-11-07 11:41:28 - Project1] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.project1/.MainActivity }
[2013-11-07 11:41:28 - Project1] ActivityManager: Error type 3
[2013-11-07 11:41:28 - Project1] ActivityManager: Error: Activity class {com.example.project1/com.example.project1.MainActivity} does not exist.
```

->Please Help me out to handle the errors.
->When I put code through dialer pad, it doesn't move to my activity page.Nothing happens after using dialer pad.

Comment: To hide the app on the launcher, why don't you try removing `<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />` in your `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Comment: yes it can make possible also